# Изменение значения SeekBar в MediaController при воспроизведении аудиозаписи

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: имеется `MediaController` для воспроизведения аудио, однако при воспроизведении, почему-то, положение `SeekBar`, который отображает какая часть песни уже проиграла, не меняется. Думал, что это должно происходить автоматически, но, судя по всему, нет. В таком случае как к нему обратиться и как менять его положение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

```
seekBar.setMax(Длинна песни в милисекундах);

for (int i = 0; i < seekBar.getMax(); i++) {
     final int k=i;
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             seekBar.setProgress(k);
             if (k>=seekBar.getMax){
                 //переключить песню
             }
         }
     },i);
}
```

Хотя возможно, если нужно обрабатывать паузу, решение окажется не самым удачным)

Comment: Да,это понятно,спасибо большое, но как можно обратиться к этому seekbar?

Comment: м, у вас сикбар из `MediaController`'а... вообще, как-то так: `mc.findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.mediacontroller_progress)`. Но по идее все должно работать и без "прямого вмешательства", возможно ошибка в чем-то другом